# Can you host Remote Desktop Services w/ RemoteFX on a Virtual Server?

Tags: remote-desktop-services, remote-desktop

Can you install RDS w/ RemoteFX on a Virtual Server?  For example Windows Server 2012 R2 hosted in AWS or Azure?

Comment: What have you done to try and find the answer yourself?

Comment: Obviously I've exhausted all other alternatives which include Colleagues, Google, other ServerFault posts, etc. and have not been able to find the answer, hence my posting of this question... Do you have any relevant knowledge to contribute to this conversation?

Comment: It's not obvious at all, the question shows a lack of research and effort so likely won't get a good response. My suggestion would be to look into improving your question, I have found the following to be a valuable resource http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Comment: @DrewKhoury This is actually a reasonable question that there isn't a whole lot of information on out there.